# How can I enter values of a string column based on values of another column in excel?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns (players) with probabilities of one boxer winning against the other boxer.

Now, I list all players against each other (there are 50, so 50*49 columns). I input probability for boxer 1 against boxer 2 as 0.2, how can I automate the process that excel automatically input probability for boxer 2 as 0.8 without me having to do that manually?

Example:

Column 1: "Mr.A" vs "Mr.B" P(Mr.A wins)=0.7

Column 2141: "Mr.B" vs "Mr.A" P(Mr.B wins)= "Excel computes that" (1-Prob boxer 1)

Comment: can you post some excel sample here

Comment: if A1 = 0.7, then put `=1-A1` formula in B2. (then drag downwards) should do.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding, you have a range of boxers listed by row and by column. Let the entry in row i column j denote the probability that fighter in row i beats fighter in column j. Then you only want to input data in 1/2 the data frame since it would be repetitive otherwise.

Something like the below example should work. The data you input is highlighted in tan. Simply copy the formula shown, hold down Ctrl and select all the cells you want to have the formula, then paste by formula.

Formula used: `=1-INDEX($B$1:$H$7, MATCH(D$1, $B$1:$B$7,0), MATCH($B2, $B$1:$H$1,0))`

[image]